# Need to make sure card is not picked more than once

Tags: java

I'm working on a project that will pull 5 cards at random and tell you what kind of hand you have. I have most of it done, however i cannot seem to put a loop on it to make sure it doesn't pull the same card twice. (i.e.I want to make sure it doesn't go 2 of hearts, 3 of hearts, 4 of diamonds, 4 of diamonds, 5 of spades).

```
int[] value= new int[5];
int[] suit= new int[5];     
for (int i =0; i< value.length; i++) {
    card = rand.nextInt(13)+2;
    value[i]=card;
}
for (int k=0; k<suit.length; k++) {
    cardSuit = rand.nextInt(4)+1;
    suit[k]=cardSuit;
}
System.out.print("\nHere are your five cards");
for (int j=0; j<5;j++) {    
    System.out.print("\n"+value[j]+" of "+suit[j]); 
}
```

Also one other thing I'm having trouble with is that I can't find a way to properly make sure that it will print Hearts instead of 1, Diamonds instead of 2, and so on and so forth. I've been using very simple stuff, so any comments that are just as simple would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: One way is to create a class `Card` and use [`Set<Card>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Set.html) to store cards to ensure uniqueness. Though, it will be more complex than your existing code, this is more usual way to doing it.

Comment: Try the official Java Tutorial. One of the exercises is creating classes for Card, Deck, Rank, and Suit. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/QandE/creating-answers.html

Answer (score 1):

I would do this by constructing your deck before drawing your cards.

```
// Use strings and pre-define our suit names.
String[] suit = { "Hearts", "Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds" };
String[] face = new String[13];
String[] deck = new String[52];

// For the number of cards of a suit
for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++) {
    // Set the value of the card face;
    String value = String.valueOf(i);
    // Replace the value for special cards
    if (i == 1 || i > 10) {
        switch(i) {
            case 11: value = "Jack";
                break;
            case 12: value = "Queen";
                break;
            case 13: value = "King";
                break;
            default: value = "Ace";
                break;
        }
    }

    // Set the face 2-10, Ace, Jack, Queen, King
    face[i-1] = value;
}

// For each suit
for (int s = 0; s < suit.length; s++) {
    // and each face value
    for (int f = 0; f < face.length; f++) {
        // add the face of that suit to the deck
        // (Ace, 2-10, Jack, Queen, King) of
        // (Hearts, Spades, Clubs, Diamonds)
        deck[(13*s)+f] = face[f] + " of " + suit[s];
    }
}

int[] handValue = new int[5];
int[] handSuit = new int[5];
int[] hand = new int[5];

// Draw 5 random cards
for( int h = 0; h < hand.length; h++ ) {
    int card = 0;
    do {
        // Do set card to a random number;
        card = rand.nextInt(52);
        // OR
        // If you want to be able to valuate the cards
        // store values separated for further calculation
        handValue[h] = rand.nextInt(13);
        handSuit[h] = rand.nextInt(4);
        card = handValue[h]*(handSuit[h]+1);
    } while (IntStream.of(hand).anyMatch(x -> x == card))
    // While the card is already in our hand
    hand[h] = card;
}

System.out.print("\nHere are your five cards");
for (int j=0; j<5; j++) {
    // Print the preformatted card value.
    System.out.print("\n" + deck[hand[j]]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish what you want is to use the same loop for both value and suit, so that you can more easily check for repeats.

```
for (int i =0; i< value.length; i++) {
    card = rand.nextInt(13)+2;
    cardSuit = rand.nextInt(4) +1;
    for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
         if(card == value[j]{
              card = rand.nextInt(13) + 2;
         }
         if(cardSuit == suit[j]{
              cardSuit = rand.nextInt(4) +1; 
         }
    }
    value[i]=card;
    suit[i]=cardSuit;
}
```

Comment: Duplicates still appear, however they seem to appear less frequently.